# Cannot run 'phonegap' command on Win 7

Tags: node.js, cordova

I've just installed phonegap on Windows 7, following the instructions on their website. However, whenever I try to run a simple 'phonegap' command, I get the error:

```
'phonegap' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I put the phonegap path at the enviroment variables 'PATH' but that didn't do anything at all.

I've also made sure WSH was enabled, but still nothing works.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out...I accidenatlly deleted some nodeJS variables while adding ant and java pathes. Had to reinstall node to realize this.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be that the path has not been updated (Have you restarted your machine?)

Alternatively, you can copy the path onto the clipboard, then in a cmd window, do the following:

```
set path=%path%;<Your path here>
```

Which will include it in your path for the current session only.

Comment: The path variable was updated :/ I tried the current session thing as well but it didn't work. No idea what's going on...

Comment: if you type echo %path% in the cmd window, can you see your path? Just to be clear, it can be added to the path on a system level, but not added to your command window sessions until after a restart

Comment: Yes, the phonegap path is included there.

Comment: The only assumption I can make then is that the path is incorrect... Other than that I'm not sure...

Comment: I've copied the absolute path from the directory, it's not incorrect :(, I'll keep trying to make this run. Thank you for your time!